# Is important the size of what I pass to the function?

Tags: php, performance, function, parameter-passing

I want to know, Should I try to pass a small value to the function? Or it doesn't matter?

For e.g :

```
$sth->execute();
function myfunc ($sth){ // do something}
```

Or

```
$sth->execute();
$end = $sth->fetch()
function myfunc ($end){ // do something}
```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. A function call's performance is not dependent on the size of the arguments. Values are handled internally so that they're essentially always passed by reference of some kind or another. It's not like PHP is making a copy of the value when passing it into a function (yes, even if it might *behave* this way in userland).